# How to ungracefully kill a program in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, copy, delete-file

I am looking to ungracefully kill a program (Chrome) in Windows 7. Chrome has a read-lock on a `.tmp` file that I want to make a copy of. If I exit Chrome gracefully Chrome deletes the `.tmp` file as it exits.

How can I immediately kill the program without letting chrome delete my file?

Comment: using Task Manager don't work? Use Chrome's internal Task Manager to kill all child process before the main process in Task Manager.

Comment: Of course task manager kill tree would be my first thought, but I am on a slow connection and the file is half a gig, so I really don't want to mess up.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to programming/code. Maybe [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) can help?

Comment: I think my best bet would be to write a script to that "attacks" chrome, making it unresponsive, then force killing it. Any ideas?

Comment: If I killed the power to my laptop (manually) do you think the file would not be deleted?

Comment: Idea that didn't work: use antivirus's quarantine on the file. "File is in use." -_- Good to know my antivirus wouldn't be able to deal with a virus that's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably uses a WinAPI temporary file, so you can't: 
Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Specifying the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY attribute causes file systems to avoid writing data back to mass storage if sufficient cache memory is available, because an application deletes a temporary file after a handle is closed. In that case, the system can entirely avoid writing the data. Although it does not directly control data caching in the same way as the previously mentioned flags, the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY attribute does tell the system to hold as much as possible in the system cache without writing and therefore may be of concern for certain applications.

You're best best is to try to copy the file while chrome is still running...
Or put a wrapper between chrome and WinAPI to override the CreateFile call so it doesn't create it as a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Chrome, use the shortcut key "Shift+Esc" to pop up the Chrome's Task Manager and kill any other processes than "Browser" (the only one that can't be killed using that).
Then, open Windows Task Manager and kill the only one "chrome.exe" that is left behind.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it deletes the file when I close the tab, not when I exit chrome, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: @nullUser Are you sure this doesn't work or just you think it doesn't work?

Comment: Just tested this in a new tab. Chrome will delete the file if I close the tab via chrome's task manager.

Comment: @nullUser How about using utilities like Unlocker to unlock the file handle?

Comment: I already tried Teracopy in combination with Unlocker. Doesn't work.

Comment: I am going to try Resource Monitor's "suspend process" on all instances of chrome.

Comment: Alright that **DIDNT** work. Suspending chrome didn't release the lock. Killing chrome (even while suspended) deleted the file. Trying file undelete programs now...

Comment: Nope, file undelete programs don't work either. It memset over where the file was... What a damn hassle this is.

Answer (score 0):

Download a software called unlocker from google.
http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/

Go to start -> search from "chrome" and go the file location. Generally this

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google

Right click on google folder and click unlocker. Click all the open handles and then start the chrome. It works!!